# Shell how to print an array of elements in pairs of ranges with comma and hyphen

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have an array of an UNKNOWN number of elements that i want to print in this format:
`item1-item2,item3-item4,item5-item6..`.

forexample: 
if myarray contains these element: `0 9 11 20 22 31 33 42`

I want to populate the output as:

```
0-9,11-20,22-31,33-42
```

so far, im only able to print it out by separating the elements with a comma. But i need to separate it in a ranges:

```
$ printf "%s-" "${myarray[@]}"
0-9-11-20-22-31-33-42-44
```

thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `printf "%d-%d," "${myarray[@]}"`:

```
$ printf "%d-%d," "${myarray[@]}"
0-9,11-20,22-31,33-42,$
```

However, that lacks a final newline and has an extra comma, so you could extend it to:

```
$ echo $(printf "%d-%d," "${myarray[@]}") | sed 's/,$//'
0-9,11-20,22-31,33-42
```

This will fail if your array doesn't have an even number of elements (it will print an extra 0):

```
$ myarray=(0 9 11 20 22 31 33)
$ echo $(printf "%d-%d," "${myarray[@]}") | sed 's/,$//'
0-9,11-20,22-31,33-0
```

You might prefer to use `%s` instead which just leaves the last one empty:

```
$ echo $(printf "%s-%s," "${myarray[@]}") | sed 's/,$//'
0-9,11-20,22-31,33-
```

And finally remove the trailing `-`:

```
$ echo $(printf "%s-%s," "${myarray[@]}") | sed 's/[,-]*$//' 
0-9,11-20,22-31,33
```

Comment: Thanks for the cool tricks. They will come in handy.

Comment: Very simple and worked great. I was over thinking it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

terdon's answer is very good. A (probably) slower, pure-bash approach would be

```
a=(0 9 11 20 22 31 33 42)
pairs=()
for ((i = 0; i < ${#a[@]}; i += 2)); do
    pairs+=( "${a[i]}-${a[i+1]}" )
done
result=$(IFS=,; echo "${pairs[*]}")
echo "$result"
```

```
0-9,11-20,22-31,33-42
```

Or

```
result=$(
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#a[@]}; i += 2)); do
        echo "${a[i]}-${a[i+1]}"
    done | paste -sd,
)
```

Or (I can't resist this kind of thing)

```
sep="-"
for elem in "${a[@]}"; do
    printf "%s%s" "$elem" $sep
    [[ $sep == "-" ]] && sep="," || sep="-"
done | sed 's/.$//'
```

Comment: Shell TIMTOWTDI! Nice :)